# Appengine urlfetch debugging

Tags: python, debugging, google-app-engine

I'm trying to do what should be a fairly simple url fetch with google appengine. However, it keeps failing.

```
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=apiurl, method=urlfetch.POST)
```

I also tried using httplib:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("api.eve-online.com")
conn.request("POST", "/char/CharacterSheet.xml.aspx", params, headers)

response = conn.getresponse()
self.response.out.write(response.read())
```

Both of these return very similar errors,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 515, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "C:\Users\Martin\Documents\google_appengine\martindevans\eveapi.py", line 24, in get
    method=urlfetch.POST)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\urlfetch.py", line 241, in fetch
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 530, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\urlfetch.py", line 315, in _get_fetch_result
    rpc.check_success()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 502, in check_success
    self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 149, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub.py", line 80, in MakeSyncCall
    method(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\urlfetch_stub.py", line 133, in _Dynamic_Fetch
    deadline=deadline)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\urlfetch_stub.py", line 223, in _RetrieveURL
    connection.request(method, full_path, payload, adjusted_headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 946, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 986, in _send_request
    self.putheader(hdr, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 924, in putheader
    str = '%s: %s' % (header, '\r\n\t'.join(values))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

I have no idea what's going on here. I'm not providing any sequences to the urlfetch method, so I'm unsure where to start debugging this.

edit: As asked, here are the headers:

```
headers = { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
```

This can't be the problem though, because the first approach doesn't even set any headers!

Comment: what's in your `headers`? the error complaint about the `header`

Comment: Added the headers in, although I don't think they can possibly be causing the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Python 2.7 ?  It supports only 2.5.2. While 2.6 mostly works, 2.7 don't.

Comment: +1 for noticing the python27 folder. Switch to Python 2.5.4 (or any other 2.5.* version) and try your code again. I think it'll work then.

Comment: Oh wow, well caught. I have several versions of python installed, how do I tell appengine which one to use?

Comment: @Martin: you can definitely use `C:/PATH/TO/PYTHON2.5 C:/PATH/TO/AppEngine/dev_appserver.py`.  I haven't used the Windows Launcher, but the Mac version has an option in the preferences to set your python executable; if you're using the launcher you might want to check for such a preference.